# Change colour of "active" stickyHeader in a Jetpack Compose LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to dynamically trigger the `color` of the `Surface` element that holds the `stickyHeader` in the Composable below, so that only the header, which is currently at the top, has a colour, whereas the rest are either transparent or have the default background colour?

I have tried using `.onGloballyPositioned`, but it produces strange behaviour, whereby the first header remains white, the second changes colour only when the third one becomes visible and the rest are always coloured, regardless of whether they are at the top.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AphorismList(
    navController: NavController,
    contentItemsList: List<AphorismAndImage>
) {

    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM")
    val groupedAphorisms = contentItemsList.groupBy { it.contentItem.date?.format(dateFormatter) ?: LocalDate.now().month }

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    var stickyHeaderPosition = 1.0F

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        groupedContentItems.forEach { (header, contentItems) ->

            stickyHeader {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            stickyHeaderPosition = it.positionInParent().y
                        },
                    color = if (stickyHeaderPosition == 0.0F) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(12.dp) else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = header.toString().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() },
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

            items(contentItems) { contentItem ->
                ContentListItem(contentItem, navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean the first index ie at 0 the header must have a color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Rajan Kali**, and after a few tiny tweaks, I managed to get it working.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AphorismList(
    navController: NavController,
    contentItemsList: List<AphorismAndImage>
) {

    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM")
    val groupedAphorisms = contentItemsList.groupBy { it.contentItem.date?.format(dateFormatter) ?: LocalDate.now().month }

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val currentHeaderState = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        groupedContentItems.forEach { (header, contentItems) ->

            stickyHeader {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            currentHeaderState.value = header.toString()
                        },
                    color = if (header == currentHeaderState.value && listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(12.dp) else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = header.toString().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() },
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

            items(contentItems) { contentItem ->
                ContentListItem(contentItem, navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess using same variable for all the headers is causing that behavior, you could create a `mutableStateOf<Header>` to hold current sticked header and update it in `onGloballyPositioned` and change colour if current header matches the state value

```
val currentHeaderState = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) } 
LazyColumn(
    state = listState, userScrollEnabled = true
) {
      groupedContentItems.forEach { (header, contentItems) ->
          stickyHeader {
                Surface(
                   modifier = Modifier
                          .fillParentMaxWidth()
                          .onGloballyPositioned {
                             if(it.positionInParent().y == 0.0F){
                                currentHeaderState.value = header
                              }
                           },
                            color = if (header == currentHeaderState.value) 
                                Color.Blue 
                            else Color.Red
                    ) {
                        Text(
                          text = header.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() },
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(8.dp)
                         )
                      }
                 }
                    
                 items(contentItems){ item ->
                     Text(
                        text = item,
                        modifier = Modifier
                             .padding(8.dp)
                     )
                 }
        }
}
```